# New external door, lots of condensation

Tags: doors, condensation

I just had a new fiberglass external door installed (with a half lite). The glass has no condensation on it, but the door itself is covered in condensation!

I installed another door at the front of my house that is also fiberglass and has no condensation on it.

The only difference between the two I can tell is that one came primed and then I had it painted and the other came in a particular color.

Updates:

- House is fairly small so the doors are in close proximity to one another.
- Install was maybe 2 months ago.
- Paint used. I'm not sure I'll have to check.

Comment: what is your interior RH / temp at the door ? I assume the two doors are located in different parts of the house.

Comment: "Just had" How recently? If it was today, is it possible it was stored in a very cold place prior to install? If the door was cold, it would condense and the windows are worse at holding temp were warmed up quicker than the door which could account for the windows not condensing.

Comment: what type of paint did you use

Comment: What color paint did you use? Where in the world are you located? What two rooms of the house are the doors installed in? Is one under an overhang (porch, door overhang, etc) and one not? Are they both insulated doors (one would expect so as "external doors", but you don't indicate if they are exterior doors). Are they the same brand/model of door? Do they both have the half lite? Please provide as many details as possible, otherwise, we're left speculating.